# Marshmello record labels

Tags: record-labels

Why does Marshmello not have a permanent record label. Why are all his songs being released under different record labels? For example, "Wolves" (2017) and "Tongue Tied" (2019)" were released under Interscope Records. "Happier" (2018) was released under Astralwerks records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of Marshmello's releases are under the labels of his collaborators.

- Selena Gomez ("Wolves"), Blackbear ("Tongue Tied"), and Yungblood ("Tongue Tied") are all signed with Interscope.
- Khalid ("Silence") is with RCA.
- Bastille ("Happier") is with Capitol, which is the distributor for Astralwerks, with whom Marshmello has signed.

Marshmello also releases under his own label, Joytime Collective.